# camel-aws: should secretKey be encoded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-camel

I'm using this kind of URI to remotely stop my instances:

```
        .to("aws-ec2://stopInstances?operation=stopInstances" +                                                                                                                                                                                       
            "&accessKey=" + accessKey +                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            "&secretKey=" + secretKey)
```

secretKey contains `+` sign. I've [found](http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2011/08/30/cloud-integration-with-apache-camel-and-amazon-web-services-aws-s3-sqs-and-sns/) that I should encode `+` sign as it's treated as `space`. Tried w/ and w/o encoding and still getting:

`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure; Request ID: XXXXX)`

Anyone have some suggestions?

**IMPORTANT** Dates on both client and server are NTP synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Solved through using:

```
...
.to("aws-ec2://stopInstances?operation=stopInstances&amazonEc2Client=#ec2Client") 
...
```

and

```
AmazonEC2Client amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));                                                                                                                                             
amazonEC2Client.setEndpoint("ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");                                                                                                                                                                                       
main.bind("ec2Client", amazonEC2Client);
```